# How to change the following output with use of apex:repeat?

Tags: visualforce, repeat

```
 <apex:pageblockSection columns="3" var="account">
                <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Account Name"/>
                <apex:inputtext value={!a.name}/>
                </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="City"/>
                <apex:inputtext value={!a.city}/>
                </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                <apex:pageblockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Country"/>
                <apex:inputtext value={!a.adress}/>
                </apex:pageblockSectionItem>

            </apex:pageblockSection>
```

I have displayed the output correctly. But i need to make this same output with the use of apex repeat tag. Can I do that ? If yes , please help me out since i want to reuse the code dynamically in future if needed

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you can proceed for `<apex:repeat>`. You need to use own CSS for look and feel. Refer [apex:repeat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_repeat.htm) at documentation.

```
<table style="width:100%" id="table1" border="1"> 
     <tr>
        <th>Account Name</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>                
    <apex:repeat id="repeat1" value="{!account}" var="a">
       <tr>
        <td><apex:inputtext value={!a.name}/></td>
        <td><apex:inputtext value={!a.city}/></td> 
        <td><apex:inputtext value={!a.adress}/></td>
      </tr>                       
  </apex:repeat>
</table>
```